# Unable to import module for locale in Angular after upgrading to Angular 13

Tags: angular, internationalization, locale, angular13

In my previous version of Angular, I used to register locale using

```
 private localeInitializer(localeId: string): Promise<any> {
    return import(
      /* webpackInclude: /(en|de)\.js$/ */
      `@angular/common/locales/${localeId}.js`
    ).then((module) => registerLocaleData(module.default));
  }
```

but now, I get error

> Module not found: Error: Package path ./locales is not exported from package ....

I checked google and changed it to below code that worked,

```
private async localeInitializer(localeId: string): Promise<any> {
    import(
      /* webpackInclude: /(en|es|id)\.mjs$/ */
      `node_modules/@angular/common/locales/${localeId}.mjs`
    ).then((module) => {
      registerLocaleData(module.default);
    });
  }
```

I get error:

> core.mjs:6495 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './de.mjs'

How to get this working ?

Comment: Are you in that case https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13865 ?

Comment: I tried the path as mentioned in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13865#issuecomment-1016639271 but still the same error.